# can anyone provide me the solution for problem in python string

Tags: python, string, split, string-concatenation

Write a function to replace concatenated or splitted tokens in
target string.

Test Case 1:
Input:
name = "salman salim khan"
record_name = "mohd salmansalim khan"
Output:
'mohd salman salim khan'
Test Case 2:
Input:
name = "salmansalim khan"
record_name = "mohd salman salim khan"
Output:
'mohd salmansalim khan'

I have tried the code as below:

```
inp1='salman salim khan'
record_name='mohd salmansalim khan'
d1=inp1.split(" ")
d2=record_name.split(" ")
for item1 in d1:
    for item2 in d2:
        if item1 in item2 or item2 in item1 or item2==item1:
            d2.remove(item2)
            d2.append(item1)
fullname=" ".join((map(str,d2)))
print(fullname)
```

but got the answer as: **"mohd salman khan"** only for Test Case1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It seems to work for the input values given. The commented out lines are just for debugging.

```py
inp1=input("Name:") #'salman salim khan'
record_name=input("Record name:") #'mohd salmansalim khan'
d1=inp1.split(" ")
d2=record_name.split(" ")
last_d1 = None
last_d2 = None
for token in d1:
    for i, token2 in enumerate(d2):
        #print(f"i={i} last_d1={last_d1} token={token} token2={token2}")
        if last_d2:
            concat = last_d2 + token2
            if concat == token: #two tokens are concatenated in input so concatenate in output
                #print("Concatenating")
                d2.remove(last_d2)
                d2.remove(token2)
                d2.insert(i-1, concat)
        if last_d1:
            concat = last_d1 + token
            #print(f"concat={concat}")
            if concat == token2: # two tokens aren't concatenated in input so split them up in output
                #print("Splitting")
                d2.remove(token2)
                d2.insert(i, last_d1)
                d2.insert(i+1, token)
        last_d2 = token2
    last_d1 = token
print(" ".join(d2))
```